# How do I show product band and model in collapsible method

Tags: php, database

How do I show brand and model in a collapsible way for product filter? Currently, I use the following code to filter data form `SQL`.

**PHP**

```
<div class="card-body pt-1" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:150px;">
    <?php
    $sca = 'Car';
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT(product_brand) FROM allpostdata WHERE sca=:sca ORDER BY (product_brand)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':sca', $sca, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            ?>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input common_selector filter_all brand" id="<?php echo $row['product_brand']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['product_brand']; ?>">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="<?php echo $row['product_brand']; ?>"><?php echo $row['product_brand']; ?></label>
            </div>
    <?php
        }
        $dbh = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

**And for Model**

```
<div class="card-body pt-1" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:150px;">
    <?php
    $sca = 'Car';
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT(product_model) FROM allpostdata WHERE sca=:sca ORDER BY (product_model)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':sca', $sca, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            ?>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input common_selector filter_all brand" id="<?php echo $row['product_model']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['product_model']; ?>">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="<?php echo $row['product_model']; ?>"><?php echo $row['product_model']; ?></label>
            </div>
    <?php
        }
        $dbh = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

But how do I show like given in image both Brand and model are in collapsible.

[image]

Comment: well you need a bit of javascript to do that

Comment: @Kevin javascript ..? any example

Comment: Don't catch the exception just to echo it. This is a terrible practice.

Comment: @Dharman is there any other way to achive that method

Comment: Yes, just remove the try/catch block. I am not sure if this is what you meant by method.

Comment: @Dharman i added Code check and let me know